# Facebook app in js to retrieve posts from a public page

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-permissions

so basically i have a wordpress website in which i want to upload the same posts of the related fb page (to this site). I created a fb app, and now i have a problem:

i cannot access the public posts of this page, without some permissions that requires an "app verification process" that are pages_read_engagement and pages_read_user_content,. I cannot also access this page's posts in other ways because i do not own the page, nor i want to be part of it just for this app.

I also do not understand why should i get my app reviewed ( i mean the review is clearly made to check there are no stolen data, but is a personal app, i won't let the access to the app to others, i will just use it as a way to automatize the process of posting to the website the same posts of the page) i didn't implemented anything yet, i cannot run it because i miss the required permissions, and the review itself shouldn't be needed for an app in test mode, I can't even log in this app using the account that owns the page just to try getting the posts as page owner because it is in test mode so no external users can log in it, so what should i do? Are there other ways to retrieve the posts from this public page?

Comment: To be able to read content of just any public page, you would need to get the Page Public Content Access feature approved. Unlikely though that they would grant it for your purpose, as you only want data from one specific page, and the allowed use case is pretty much only to "provide competitive benchmark analysis" anyway.

Comment: _"I cannot also access this page's posts in other ways because i do not own the page"_ - you would need to implement the login flow, so that a page admin can grant your app permissions & access to the page.

Comment: _"I can't even log in this app using the account that owns the page just to try getting the posts as page owner because it is in test mode so no external users can log in it"_ - you can log in using your own account and test & develop using a page you have access to; you can also ask the page admin to become a tester of your app (their account needs to be registered as a developer for that to work.)

Comment: @CBroe it's ok for me, as this app is made only for this page. It has a single purpose. When I try to log in with the user that owns the page, I get told that the app is in debug mode and is not safe. The only way is to give this user the permissions from the admin of the app (me) but i couldn't find anything on the app dashboard to give permission access.

Comment: You don't grant permissions for other users from the app dashboard. You add them as a test user, so that they can grant the permissions themselves, via the login flow. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-roles#tester

Comment: I added the account who owns the page as tester, but still upon login it says the app is not configured yet. If you meant "test users" is not useful as they are just "bots" from what I saw

Comment: Did they receive a notification and _accept_ the request to become a tester of your app? As noted in the docs, they must have a Facebook developer account.

Comment: They are not, and nor i would make their account a dev one. It's a weird solution for me. The only thing to do is to complete the review to obtain the necessary permission to access the page as a public page. No escapes from this